# Azure AD app with Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy cannot add more owners to apps it created

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an AAD app that creates other AAD apps. The first app (creator) has right `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` and is able to update display names of the apps it created but it is not able to add more owners on those apps. Does it need more privileges to do that?

HTTP request updating the created-app display name (succeeds):

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/applications/a1236923-6de6-4e78-87dd-494d621fc20c?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi...
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Length: 45
Expect: 100-continue

{
  "displayName": "test"
}
```

HTTP request adding an owner to the created-app (fails):

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/applications/a1236923-6de6-4e78-87dd-494d621fc20c/$links/owners?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi...
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.windows.net
Content-Length: 122
Expect: 100-continue

{
  "url": "https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/users/ac990eb3-b25a-4e06-ade5-41c7613693ff"
}


HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
request-id: 9be47e62-abcd-4768-926f-ffd62544e696
client-request-id: 149115f6-c9b7-4dd4-a267-711a40c51f23
...

{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

I verified that the creator app does indeed have `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` in the roles array of the JWT Bearer token.

I also verified that the creator app is present in the owner list of the created app by calling `GET https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/applications/a1236923-6de6-4e78-87dd-494d621fc20c/owners/64898a3a-2fb1-45f0-a514-e83fabbc01f2`.

Comment: You are using AAD graph not the MS graph, you missed a `Directory.Read.All` permission of your creator app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in order to add an owner, the calling app (and the calling user, in the case of delegated permissions, though in this case it's an app only) needs to have the permission to read the object of the owner being added, as well as the permission to read and write to the object which is being given a new owner.

Thus, in order for an app to add a *User* object as an owner to an *Application* object that the calling  app is itself an owner of, the app needs (at least) `Directory.Read.All` (to read the new owner's *User* object), and `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` (to be able to write to the *Application* object's list of owners).

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, you do not have enough privileges. As far as I known, if you want to assign user to AAD Application with Application privileges, you need to have these privileges : Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy and Directory.Read.All, Application.ReadWrite.All and Directory.Read.All.

Besides, Microsoft strongly recommends that you use [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/) instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources. For more details, please refer to the [article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/). If you want to use Microsoft graph api to assign user to AAD Application, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-owners?view=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! We hit some gaps in MS Graph in that particular case that precluded its use, but MS Graph is what we otherwise go to.